# Inserting data to multiple table in my sqlworkbench

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm a new coder trying to code C# to insert data into sqlworkbench database. Having alot of problems. Looking for any help. Thanks.

```
    private void enterbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        string myConnectionString;

        myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
            "pwd=;database=mydb;";

        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into garden(idGarden) VALUES (@idGarden)");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idGarden", gardentextBox.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into rainfall(aveRainfall) VALUES (@aveRainfall)");
        cmd1.Connection = conn;
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aveRainfall", aveRaintextBox.Text);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd1.Parameters.Clear();           
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into seat(idSeat) VALUES (@idSeat)");
        cmd2.Connection = conn;
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSeat", seatIDtextBox.Text);
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd2.Parameters.Clear();          
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into temperature(currentTemp) VALUES (@currentTemp)");
        cmd3.Connection = conn;
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentTemp", currentTemptextBox.Text);
        cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd3.Parameters.Clear();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What are the problems exactly? You get any error or exception message? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: executeNonQuery.connection not properly initialized and the scalar variable not declared error. i tried cmd.connection = conn to establish connection but it didnt work. :/

Comment: And why do you use `SqlCommand` with `MySqlConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't connect your `SqlCommand`'s with your `MySqlConnection`. And I think they should `MySQLSqlCommand` instead of `SqlCommand`.

You can assing their [`.Connection` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your `MySqlConnection`. Like;

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd2.Connection = conn;
cmd3.Connection = conn;
cmd4.Connection = conn;
```

And you try to execute your `cmd` only. I think you should execute your all others commands like `cmd2`, `cmd3` and `cmd4`..

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And could be better to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections..

```
using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString))
using(MySQLCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   //
}
```

Also always prefer to use [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`AddWithValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Read: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd2.Connection = conn;
cmd3.Connection = conn;
cmd4.Connection = conn;

I tried the above and give me errors. Error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: @user3796533 as I said my answer, if you use SQL client, you need to use `SqlConnection` with `SqlCommand`, if you use MySQL client you need to use `MySqlConnection` with `MySqlCommand`